# Error on creating Message Hub service

Tags: ibm-cloud, account, message-hub

I got the following error while creating IBM Message Hub service. Could you please help to check what causes this error?

```
Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error getting account info with org guid = b3213773-a799-43bd-9e7e-41c9636f40f9, error = empty account."}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please raise a ticket using the IBM Cloud support service. The ticket should be directed to the IBM Cloud BSS team. This sounds like an issue with your account rather than anything else.